# What's wrong with my sql query?

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO jos_race_calendrier_regional (id, evt_code, evt_date_comp, evt_station, evt_activite, evt_comite, evt_club_num, evt_club_nom, evt_nom, evt_dt, org_nom, org_adresse, org_adresse2, org_adresse3, org_ville, org_site, cont_nom, cont_tel, cont_gsm, cont_fax, cont_mail, epr_codex, epr_date, epr_sexe, epr_regroupement, epr_grille_categorie, epr_categorie, epr_discipline, epr_distance, epr_homologation') VALUES ( '79', 'evt_code', 'evt_date_comp', 'evt_station', 'evt_activite', 'evt_comite', 'evt_club_num', 'evt_club_nom', 'evt_nom', 'evt_dt', 'org_nom', 'org_adresse1', 'org_adresse2', 'org_adresse3', 'org_ville', 'org_site', 'cont_nom', 'cont_tel', 'cont_gsm', 'cont_fax', 'cont_mail', 'epr_codex', 'epr_date', 'epr_sexe', 'epr_regroupement', 'epr_grille_categorie', 'epr_categorie', 'epr_discipline', 'epr_distance_style', 'epr_homologation')
```

i am getting following  error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '') VALUES ( '79', 'evt_code', 'evt_date_comp', 'evt_station', 'evt_activite', 'e' at line 1

Comment: If you formatted your question properly, you would see the error right in the preview.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized now that it is solved

Comment: @Pekka: Is that some new SO convention to follow? I haven't been in the loop. (I'd asked the mods on Twitter about that close reason just the other day, though.)

Comment: @Pekka: too localized? Are you trying to tell us only a French can misplace a quote? :)

Comment: @BoltClock no, that was just my idea, nothing official. Out of the feeling that syntax error issues usually have zero value to future generations. @Quassnoi no, that's defn'tly an interna'tional pheno'menon. In my experience, the French  actually take this stuff pretty seriously! I've been in serious trouble over innocently mixing up `\`` and `´` accents in French words.  :)

Comment: @Pekka: The duke yet lives that Henry shall depose

Answer (score 6):

The error message has already told you where your syntax error is (near), so you should look at your code again to find out what's wrong yourself, but I'll just pinpoint it to the very character for you now.

You have a misplaced single quote here:

```
epr_homologation') VALUES
```

Should be

```
epr_homologation) VALUES
```

Answer (score 3):

Extra quote after `epr_homologation`:

```
INSERT INTO jos_race_calendrier_regional (id, evt_code, evt_date_comp, evt_station, evt_activite, evt_comite, evt_club_num, evt_club_nom, evt_nom, evt_dt, org_nom, org_adresse, org_adresse2, org_adresse3, org_ville, org_site, cont_nom, cont_tel, cont_gsm, cont_fax, cont_mail, epr_codex, epr_date, epr_sexe, epr_regroupement, epr_grille_categorie, epr_categorie, epr_discipline, epr_distance, epr_homologation) VALUES ( '79', 'evt_code', 'evt_date_comp', 'evt_station', 'evt_activite', 'evt_comite', 'evt_club_num', 'evt_club_nom', 'evt_nom', 'evt_dt', 'org_nom', 'org_adresse1', 'org_adresse2', 'org_adresse3', 'org_ville', 'org_site', 'cont_nom', 'cont_tel', 'cont_gsm', 'cont_fax', 'cont_mail', 'epr_codex', 'epr_date', 'epr_sexe', 'epr_regroupement', 'epr_grille_categorie', 'epr_categorie', 'epr_discipline', 'epr_distance_style', 'epr_homologation')
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if 'id' is an int, you don't put `''` around it.